# Where are they being held?

Tags: cipher

In my dream, some People asked me for help. They said I should wake up. So I woke up and there was this letter.

> Dear Percy
>
> We got caught and only you can help us. You've 60 minutes **(try it and let me know if you passed it)**.
>   We hate him, but got Rom and ask for help. You need 3 Whooxulxp and 13 Ulqebtra. If you got this put the 13 Ulqebtra between 3 Whooxulxp. Now you have the first part, for the next you need the help from Feboryei.
>
> If you found him, ask him for 53 24 24. He will know what this should mean. You also can ask him from where he comes. That could eventually become useful.
>
> The third part is, search the author R.R. He wrote about us, and our childrens who saved the world. In his book, we are at the moment in the Empire State Building. Normally we are on the top of the mountain in the country where Feboryei lived. I would tell you the name of our home, but I forgot it. You have to find it out.
>
> After you found it, got to the harbor. 
>   The captain  with the ship ASC2 can certainly help you with the next part.
>   (.---- ----- ...-- / .---- .---- .---- / .---- ----- ----- / .---- .---- .....)
>
> Now you should know who we are. But you don't know  where to find us.
>   **"Siblings of the number 3, 1 got excluded. He is a king. But don't get any respect. Everyone is afraid of him. Under the ground, is where he lives"**

**Tip: Go from part to part or it will be hard.**

**Little Hint:**

> Every part will give you a Word. In the End you will know who you should safe

**Who do I have to save? And where?**

Comment: This should be harder than my last cipher. I hope you'll enjoy it ;) and gl

Comment: @ M Oehm yes you're right, my fault.

Comment: No swaet. I'll delete my comment and pretend it didn't happen ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you have

> TELLURIUM and HYDROGEN (after de-Caesaring by the given amounts), putting H between T and E we get **THE**.

Next, Feboryei

> de-Caesars to make POLYBIOS, presumably pointing to the Polybius square cipher. Then 53 24 24 yields XII (if we use the Roman alphabet) or ΨΚΚ (if we use the Greek alphabet). Probably the former; we probably want the word **TWELVE**.

The author is

> presumably Rick Riordan, author of the Percy Jackson books, and our next word is **OLYMPIAN**.

And then we have

> Morse code for digits forming the ASCII positions of **GODS**.

Unfortunately

> there doesn't seem to be a canonical ordering for THE TWELVE OLYMPIAN GODS. The obvious guess given the text we have is that we are looking for **Hades/Pluto** (one of three siblings, the two others being Zeus and Poseidon; he is the king of the underworld and as such commands fear rather than respect, and indeed he lives under the ground).

Given that that last bit is described as "where", perhaps the answer is that

> someone has kidnapped the gods of Olympus and taken them to the (ex-)planet Pluto?

Comment: I was hoping that it would take longer to solve it. +1 But you did a great job. Everything is right so well done ;), to the last point they are not on the planet pluto but in his kingdom in the underground called after him Hades.